# How do I display the reputation points in K?

Tags: support, reputation, profile-page

I have 10,000 reputation points on Stack Overflow. I see users having reputation of more than 10,000 is displayed like 10K. Do I have to configure it or does Stack Overflow do it automatically after some time?

Comment: Where are you looking? After 10k (like you), on question list pages, questions and answers, you automatically get the 'k' thing. In the topbar and on your profile page however, it will always show the exact rep value.

Comment: There's nothing for you to configure.

Comment: Looks like "10K" to me... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721242/why-interface-default-methods

Comment: Anyway, writing 10 000 as “10 k” or even worse “10k” is wrong since prefix symbols shall not stand alone. “10 K” is right out since K is the symbol for the unit kelvin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically done.

Well kinda; users may view your exact reputation by clicking on your profile and viewing it. However for general questions and answers it will show the rounded lower k (on desktop)

[image: Rep]

The app however will always show a user's full reputation.